# How to do a Jquery Sortable cancel inside ajax function?

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Sortable for dragging table rows , and once the drag completes i am using ajax call for  updating the status to Database .
Incase the ajax call fails , how to cancel the sort operation ??

Inside the ajax call i have used

```
$( this ).sortable( "cancel" );
```

where i am getting in console

```
VM107 jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'cancel'
```

and this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr)
        {
                var $originals = tr.children();
                var $helper = tr.clone();
                $helper.children().each(function(index)
                {
                        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
                });
                return $helper;
        };
        $("#sort tbody").sortable(
        {
                helper: fixHelperModified,
                delay: 175,
                start: function(e, ui)
                {
                        var pac_id = ui.item.attr('pac_id');
                        $(this).attr('data-pac_id', pac_id);
                        $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
                },
                stop: function(e, ui)
                {
                        var newIndex = ui.item.index() + 1;
                        var oldIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-previndex')) + 1;
                        var pac_id = $(this).attr('data-pac_id');
                        var inputjson = {
                                'pac_id': pac_id,
                                'old_position': oldIndex,
                                'new_position': newIndex
                        };
                        var reqested_data = JSON.stringify(inputjson);
                        var ajaxres = '';
                        $.ajax(
                        {

                               success: function(response)
                                {
                                     if(2<3)
                                     {
                                        $( this ).sortable( "cancel" );
                                     }

                                },
                                 error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                                {
                                $( this ).sortable( "cancel" );
        alert('please try again');
                                }


                        }).done(function() {});
                        $(this).removeAttr('data-previndex');
                        $(this).removeAttr('data-pac_id');
                },
        }).disableSelection();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/33keyjxx/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel the sortable for the element that you initialized the sortable plugin,

`this` in this context will refer to the success function of the ajax call not the stop function of your sortable

```
 $("#sort tbody").sortable("cancel");
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/g2vgaffm/

Answer (score 1):

**$(this)** element you cannot call inside the ajax. So assign some variable and call this.

The following

```
 $.ajax({
```

**into**

```
var elem = $(this);
$.ajax({
```

The following

```
$( this ).sortable( "cancel" );
```

**into**

```
elem.sortable( "cancel" );
```

Comment: @UnKnown Welcome :-)